# labels instead of color in bar plot

Tags: matlab, label, bar-chart

I want to display labels in a bar plot (and if possible, remove the color). For example, here's a code snippet that create a bar plot in color:

```
S=[1 4 1 2 3 4];
R=[4 4 4 10 6 1];
f=zeros(5,6);
for i=1:5
 for j=1:numel(S)
     if S(j)==i
     f(i,j)=R(j);
  end
 end
end
barplot=bar(f,'stacked');
```

What I want is something that looks like this:

[image]

How can I do it? Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would really help if you post an image of a sample output plot.

Comment: there's no easy way of doing this. You can draw text in the plot with `text`, but you will probably want to draw the bars yourself using `fill` in that case. It's tedious.

Comment: hi, eitan...:( actually my reputation is low so I can't send image...but if you give me your email address i'll send it for you

Comment: @MahyarMajlesee You can upload an image to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and edit the link the image into your question, or even post it as a comment, and I'll embed it as an image for you. Oh, by the way, you already posted [an identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258785)... If you don't get any answers, I recommend revising and improving that question by editing instead of re-posting it as a new one.

Comment: @eitan yahh eitan, i already asked like question, but i thought if i ask it in this way probably it'll be better,by the way you're alright. i uploaded it, http://imgur.com/P6R8rzG

Comment: @MahyarMajlesee The image you've given is the result of the code above, not the output that you want... and perhaps it is best that you delete your old question then, to avoid duplicate questions.

Comment: @EitanT sure dear eitan, i'll delete my old question, i uploaded the image i want. actually in this image data(number) shows the columns in the matrix f.  http://imgur.com/S2kiTb8

Comment: @MahyarMajlesee Thanks. I've embedded the image into your question for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to remove the color of the bars (*i.e* make the bars) you can make use of the vector of handles returned by `bar`:

```
set(barplot, 'FaceColor', 'w'); % // w = white
```

Adding text to the bar plot is a little trickier -- you'll have to add individual text labels using [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html), and in order to do that, you must calculate the x and y coordinates for each label. Here's how it can be done:

```
H = nonzeros(R) / 2;            % // Relative offset of each text label 
Y = cumsum(f, 2);
Y = nonzeros(Y(f > 0)') - H;    %'// Y coordinates of text labels
X = S - 0.2;                    % // X coordinates of text labels
for k = 1:numel(Y)
    text(X(k), Y(k), labels{k}) % // Show text label
end
```

where `labels` is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of the text strings to be displayed.

By the way, you can reduce your two nested loops into one single statement:

```
f = full(sparse(S, 1:numel(S), R, 5, numel(S)));
```

#### Example

```
S = [1 4 1 2 3 4];
R = [4 4 4 10 6 1];

%// Bar plot
f = full(sparse(S, 1:numel(S), R, 5, numel(S)));
barplot = bar(f, 'stacked');

%// Set color of bars to white
set(barplot, 'FaceColor', 'w')

%// Add text labels
labels = {'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6'};
H = nonzeros(R) / 2;
Y = cumsum(f, 2);
Y = nonzeros(Y(f > 0)') - H;     %'// Y coordinates
X = S - 0.2;                     % // X coordinates
for k = 1:numel(Y)
    text(X(k), Y(k), labels{k})
end
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: result]

Have fun :)

Comment: your answer was so good dear eitan...you're definitely expert.Thanks so so so lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay to put the labels in the x-axis tick labels, consider using http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722-rotate-tick-label instead. You might be able to modify it to automatically put the text vertically inside each bar, but I do not recommend it.